# ZipException: duplicate entry on Kotlin classes

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

Please note this project compiled successfully before upgrading to Android Studio 3.1, Gradle build tools 3.1.0 and Gradle Wrapper 4.4.

The exception occurs during the Gradle task transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForSomethingDebug:

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/me/utils/model/singleModel/NodeModel.class
```

Please note that the exception only occurs on Kotlin classes (like NodeModel above). If I remove this class, the exception will occur on the very next Kotlin class.

All of the other questions on SO that mention this exception were somehow related to duplicate third party libraries from within project dependencies. This is however not my case, as NodeModel is a custom class that I wrote myself. It's actually just a simple Kotlin data class.

The project is using Kotlin version 1.2.30, build tools 27.0.3, support library 27.1.0 and Firebase 12.0.1.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project several times, changing between my local JDK and the embedded one, nothing works.

I tried running Gradle with --stacktrace --debug in order to find out where is the duplicate coming from, but the Gradle logs did not mention anything relevant.

Comment: Did you tried invalidate caches and restart ?

Comment: @sunil Yes I have, same result though.

Comment: Known issue for multi-module projects. Check this article: https://medium.com/@terrakok/how-to-fix-gradle-build-error-java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-83d102038056

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Even with the workaround mentioned below, I was still getting the occasional exception. Now that Android Studio 3.1.1 has been released, the issue has disappeared completely. Just make sure to also update to version 3.1.1 of the Gradle build tools, and at least version 4.4 of the Gradle wrapper:

In `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

In the project's `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        ...
    }
}
```

**Initial answer**

Increasing the Gradle Wrapper version to 4.6 fixed it for me, but only temporarily. The exception occured again the next day.

The only working solution I found so far is to downgrade the Gradle Wrapper back to 4.3.1, and the Gradle build tools to 3.0.0, until a new stable version of the Gradle build tools is available.

In `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3.1-all.zip
```

In the project's `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this fix still working? I'm having the same issue with latest Android version, Gradle 4.4 and Gradle plugin 3.1.2

Comment: me too getting this intermediately, its annoying :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, only that it was not working for me when modifying previously compiled file (clean build would work).
Changing Android Gradle Plugin to 3.2.0-beta02 from 3.1.3 solved this for me.

Answer (score -1):

Solve the problem with splitting the java and kotlin sources in separate modules.
Do not mix java and kotlin in one module. 
It creates some weird errors about duplication, even I have one class only